# converge sequence with floor function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\lim{a_n}=L$ and $f(x)=a_{\lfloor{x\rfloor}}(\lfloor{x\rfloor}+1-x)+a_{\lfloor{x\rfloor}+1}(x-\lfloor{x\rfloor})$.

Show that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}} f(x) =L$ for $L\in \Bbb R$.

I couldn't start the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
(\lfloor{x\rfloor}+1-x)+(x-\lfloor{x\rfloor})=1,
$$
and write
$$
L=(\lfloor{x\rfloor}+1-x)L+(x-\lfloor{x\rfloor})L.
$$
Now consider $f(x)-L$.

Comment: $f(x)-L=(a_{\lfloor{x\rfloor}}-L)(\lfloor{x\rfloor}+1-x)+(a_{\lfloor{x\rfloor}+1}-L)((x-\lfloor{x\rfloor})$